# $\mathcal{L}(R^3)\longleftarrow$ What is this?

Tags: linear-algebra

As title says, what does $\mathcal{L}(R^3)$ mean? I have found it a couple of times but I don't understand what it stands for.

Comment: linear transformations from $R^3$ to $R^3$,maybe?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг books are really making things confusing. Typically they will write $L(V,V)$ in which you say, "oh, well these are maps from $V$ to $V$." In this abbreviation, it's a real gamble.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood No, this one I have seen pretty often. especially when the question is tagged "linear algebra". Though I agree, it is very very confusing at times.